# Why are there no potential operators that are non-diagonal in position basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy, hamiltonian

The potential energy operator in the Hamilton operator can be expressed in the following way
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat V &=\int dx\int dx'|x \rangle\langle x|\hat V|x'\rangle \langle x'| \\
&=\int dx\int dx'|x \rangle V(x,x') \langle x'| \, .\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Why is it legit to assume that the potential has the follwing form
$$
V(x,x') = \delta(x-x')\tilde V(x)
$$
effectively removing the dependency on the second variable leading to the common form
$$
\hat V =\int dx \ |x\rangle \tilde V(x) \langle x| \, .
$$
Are there potentials that are non diagonal in position basis or are all physically meaningful potentials diagonal ?

I am mostly wondering because I started with a general expression of the form
$$
\langle \Psi|\hat H|\Psi\rangle =\int\int dx dx' \langle \Psi|x\rangle \langle x|\hat H |x'\rangle \langle x'|\Psi\rangle \, ,
$$
and then inserting $\hat H = \hat T + \hat V$ leads then to terms as described above for the potential, but all Hamiltonians I have seen so far in position basis are assumed to have only a $V(x)$ term implying the diagonal form.

Comment: Possible search term: *"velocity dependent potential"*?

Comment: A potential that depends on more than one position is basically a particle/field interacting with itself, which can happen especially if you use math tricks to get rid of  the part of the Hamiltonian representing other particles/fields.

Comment: You could have nonlocal interactions. So far there is no experimental evidence for such interactions. Nonlocal interactions can give you off-diagonal terms. (I do not think that velocity-dependent terms do that per se @dmckee.)