# Matrix elements of operators in position representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, linear-algebra

In a lecture note, it is written
$$
T_{ij} = \langle \phi_i| \hat{T} | \phi_j \rangle 
= \int d^3 \vec{r} \phi_i^*(\vec{r}) T(\vec{r}) \phi_j(\vec{r})
$$
How to obtain the second integral form from the first one?

Comment: In many approaches, these would be equivalent pretty much by definition. Unless you give us your definitions of $\langle \phi_i \vert A\vert\phi_j\rangle$ and/or of $\phi_i(\vec r)$, I don't see how this could be usefully answered.

Comment: You insert twice the resolution of identity $1 = \int |r\rangle \langle r| dr$ of the position basis in between the operator and the bra and ket, then you perform one of the integrals while using the orthogonality relation $\langle r|r'\rangle =\delta(r-r') $.

Answer (score 3):

In one improper basis as $|\mathbf{r}\rangle$ we have the resolution of the identity in the following form $$\int d^3\mathbf{r} |\mathbf{r}\rangle\langle \mathbf{r}|=\mathbf{1}\tag{1}.$$

Now since this is just the identity operator you can insert it wherever you want, that being one *very common* manipulation in QM. In particular you may insert it in between $\langle \phi_i|$ and $\hat{T}$ and in between $\hat{T}$ and $|\phi_j\rangle$:

$$\langle \phi_i|\hat{T}|\phi_j\rangle=\langle \phi_i|\mathbf{1}\hat{T}\mathbf{1}|\phi_j\rangle=\int d^3\mathbf{r}d^3\mathbf{r}' \langle \phi_i|\mathbf{r}\rangle\langle \mathbf{r}|\hat{T}|\mathbf{r}'\rangle\langle \mathbf{r}'|\phi_j\rangle\tag{2}.$$

Now we recognize the wavefunctions $\phi_i^\ast(\mathbf{r})=\langle \phi_i|\mathbf{r}\rangle$ and $\phi_i(\mathbf{r}')=\langle\mathbf{r}'|\phi_j\rangle$, and we *define* $\hat{T}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}'):=\langle \mathbf{r}|\hat{T}|\mathbf{r}'\rangle$. In that case the general thing is that

$$\langle \phi_i|\hat{T}|\phi_j\rangle=\int d^3\mathbf{r}d^3\mathbf{r}' \phi_i^\ast(\mathbf{r})\phi_j(\mathbf{r})\hat{T}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}')\tag{3}.$$

Now your equation holds true for the particular case in which $\hat{T}$ is one diagonal operator in the position basis: $\hat{T}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}')=\hat{T}(\mathbf{r})\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$.

Comment: Yes, I think this is correct. So, is this delta function form of the operator a must for any observable? Or any particular class (e.g., non-interacting potential only).

Comment: It's certainly not true for any operator. To give you an anlogy picture operators in finite-dimensional spaces. If $M$ is such an operator and $|i\rangle$ is a basis you get matrix elements $M_{ij}=\langle i | M| j\rangle$. The analogous form in this case would be a diagonal matrix $M_{ij} = \lambda_i \delta_{ij}$. Is every matrix diagonal? Certainly not. And so it is the case for operators represented like this. Nevertheless, a lot of the potentials we encounter are of this form, but nothing forbids the most general form.

Comment: In particular see this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/486817/why-are-there-no-potential-operators-that-are-non-diagonal-in-position-basis